# How to add pre-commit git hooks to check that README.Rmd and index.Rmd have been knitted?

Tags: r, githooks, r-package, pkgdown, r-usethis

I have an R package with a pkgdown documentation site.  I want to create a git hook so that if I try to commit and push changes to either `README.Rmd` or `index.Rmd` without first knitting them to create the corresponding `.Md` files, I'm warned.  Right now I just forget.

The book [R Packages](https://r-pkgs.org/whole-game.html?q=hook#use_readme_rmd) says to use `usethis::use_readme_rmd()` to create the README, which will also create the git hook.  But I already have a README.Rmd file.

How can I create a hook for an existing .Rmd file generally, whether it's README.Rmd or the index.Rmd from my pkgdown site?  I'd like to use the `usethis` package but if it's simpler to do it outside of that package, I'm open to that.

Comment: This is the line from the use_readme_rmd function: `use_git_hook("pre-commit", render_template("readme-rmd-pre-commit.sh"))`       you can see that by just typing the name of the function with no ().

Comment: I got that far, now I'm unclear on how to modify `usethis:::render_template("readme-rmd-pre-commit.sh")` to work on `index.Rmd`.  It's an unexported function and I can't find any documentation.  How do others set up their `index.Rmd` to auto-knit?

Comment: Why don't you use the rmarkdown render() function?

Comment: Can I create the git hook for `index.Rmd` with `render()`?

Answer (score 0):

A different approach is to do this with Github Actions if that is where your pkgdown site is.

1. Create the folder `.github` within your repo
2. Within that create the folder `workflows`
3. Within that create the file `render-readme.yml`
4. Paste this code in that file

```
on:
  push:
    paths:
      - README.Rmd
      - Index.Rmd

name: Render README and Index

jobs:
  render:
    name: Render README and Index
    runs-on: macOS-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r@v1
      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-pandoc@v1
      - name: Install packages
        run: Rscript -e 'install.packages(c("rmarkdown", "knitr"))'
      - name: Render README
        run: Rscript -e 'rmarkdown::render("README.Rmd", output_format = "md_document")'
      - name: Render Index
        run: Rscript -e 'rmarkdown::render("Index.Rmd", output_format = "md_document")'
      - name: Commit results
        run: |
          git commit README.md -m 'Re-build README.Rmd' || echo "No changes to commit"
          git commit Index.md -m 'Re-build Index.Rmd' || echo "No changes to commit"
          git push origin || echo "No changes to commit"
```

5. Push this to GitHub and it should start working immediately. Note it takes a bit of time to process. Click on the Actions tab in your GitHub repo to see the progress.

See https://github.com/r-lib/actions for examples. Code above is adapted from that.

Note you might want to divide the action into 2 files. `render-readme.yml` and `render-index.yml`. That way if the Action fails, you'll know which file has the problem.

Comment: thank you for this answer! I can't give it a shot for a while, but when I do try it I'll delete this comment and reply/accept/vote accordingly.